# Envío de datos de ViewHolder a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, callback

No recibo en *MiDialogFragment* instanciado por un evento de click desde *MiAdapter.MiHolder* los extras (un *int* y un *String*) que preparo en un *Bundle*.

#### MiDialogFragment

```
public class MiDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    // FIELDS.......................................................................................

    public final static String TAG = MiDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Integer entero;
    private String cadena;

    // METHODS......................................................................................

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_mi_dialog_fragment, null);

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        entero = extras.getInt("ENTERO");
        cadena = extras.getString("CADENA");

        Log.d(TAG, "entero: " + entero);
        Log.d(TAG, "cadena: " + cadena);

        /* ... Más código ... */

        return v;
    }

    /* ... Más código ... */

}
```

#### MiAdapter.MiViewHolder

```
// ADAPTER..........................................................................................

public class MiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MiAdapter.FriendHolder> {

    // FIELDS.......................................................................................

    private static final String TAG = MiAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private List<MiObjeto> objetos;

    // METHODS......................................................................................

    public FriendAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<MiObjeto> objetos) {
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        this.objetos = objetos;
    }

    @Override
    public MiHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_objeto, parent, false);
        return new MiHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MiHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.entero = objetos.get(position).getEntero();
        /* ... Más código ... */
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objetos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        objetos.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    // VIEW HOLDER..................................................................................

    public class MiHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        // FIELDS...................................................................................

        private int entero;
        private View mVista1;
        private View mVista2;
        private View mVista3;

        // METHODS..................................................................................

        public MiHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mVista1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vista1View);
            mVista2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vista2View);
            mVista3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vista3View);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // Bind Listener
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { 

            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new MiDialogFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("ENTERO", entero)
            bundle.putString("CADENA", ((TextView)mVista1).getText.toString());
            dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, MiDialogFragment.TAG);
        }

    }

    // ITEM TOUCH HELPER............................................................................

    public static class MiTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

        // FIELDS...................................................................................

        private int entero;
        private MiAdapter miAdapter;
        private Context mContext;

        // METHODS..................................................................................

        public MiTouchHelper(int entero, MiAdapter miAdapter, Context context) {
            super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
            this.entero = entero;
            this.miAdapter = miAdapter;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            /* ... Más código **/
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            /* ... Más código **/
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que realizar es enviar los datos a traves del `bundle` cuando instancias el `DialogFragment` mediante `setArguments()` para que puedan ser leídos en el `onCreate()` :

```
public static MiDialogFragment newInstance() {    
    MiDialogFragment frag = new MiDialogFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("ENTERO", 12);
    bundle.putString("CADENA", "Hola StackOverflow");
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    return frag;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no había caído. Yo intentaba capturarlo en el onActivityResult del Fragment con DialogFragment#setTargetFragment. Ya funciona :)

Comment: Que bien @dddenis me alegra.